# "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements

Tags: html, angular, npm, frontend, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to get my frontend-application(Angular5.1.x) to run but it stops due to template parse error:

```
"let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("
</thead>
<tbody>
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="rows" [ERROR ->]let-rowz="$implicit" let-    index="index">
<tr *ngIf="!(datePicker.onlyCurrentMonth && rowz[0].sec"):     
ng:///DatepickerModule/DayPickerComponent.html@52:58
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:24633)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:34442)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:34417)
    at compiler.js:34318
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:34318)
    at compiler.js:34188
    at Object.then (compiler.js:474)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34187)
```

I figured I need to follow this on-topic issue, stating I need to use ngx-bootrap@ngx-bootstrap@2.0.0-beta.8, but it doesnt work with that or v.2.0.0-rc.0

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3024

...any help is appreciated

Comment: why cant you write ng-template instead of template ?

Comment: Template is deprecated, you should use ng-template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are no `<template>` tags in v2+, please do clean install,
and check that you have ngx-bootstrap v2+
check package lock if present

Comment: Thank you for the feedback valorkin, in the end I had to do an 'npm cache clear --force' as well for it to work.

Comment: I removed my node modules, did `npm cache clear --force`, and I still have this issue. Using `"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2"`, and `"ngx-date-picker": "0.0.24"`.

Comment: Remove package lock json file and do it again

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: I created a new node project, and imported ngx-date-picker. Version number is 0.0.24. There are several `template` tags in there.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my module so I can't help, but you can use datepicker from ngx-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my ngx-bootstrap and 'npm cache clear --force', Its worked for me.

Comment: I have updated bootstrap, cleared cache, and there was no <template tag for me to replace. Even it is showing same error for me

Answer (score 11):

I have encountered this error when upgraded from Angular 4.x.x to 5.x.x. Original code was:

```
<template let-item>

</template>
```

This worked fine in Angular 4, but failed in 5. Simply using `ng-template` worked correctly (no packages installation was required, no cache clean required):

```
<ng-template let-item>

</ng-template>
```

Comment: you may need to make it #let-item

Answer (score 7):

`ngx-bootstrap 1.x.x` using `<template>` which has been deprecated in `angular 5.x.x`. so you have to upgrade to `ngx-bootstrap 2.X.X`

Do following to upgrade

```
npm uninstall --save ngx-bootstrap
npm cache clean -f
npm install --save ngx-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 2):

Just search all

1. `<template` and replace with `<ng-template`
2. `</template>` and replace with `</ng-template>`

Answer (score 0):

It was also facing the same issue. by the issue found that the array which i created was

```
<ng-template  ngFor [ngForOf]="names" let-name="$implicit" let-i="index">
  <div><span>{{i+1}}</span> <span> {{name.name}}</span></div>
</ng-template>
```

like :-

```
names= [{id:1,name:'shashikant'},{id:2,name:'Rakesh'},{id:3,name:'Umesh'}];
```

then i replace by :-

```
names:Array<any>= [{id:1,name:'shashikant'},{id:2,name:'Rakesh'},{id:3,name:'Umesh'}];
```

**specified the type to Array**

Answer (score 0):

You do not use ng-template tags in html file but you have import ngx module to you app.model.ts
then this will come. remove your app.model import statement and build and check.

thank you.

Answer (score -3):

I face the same problem and replacing `<template>` tag by `<ng-template>` in my html files I solved the issue.